# RxJs javascript - bindNodeCallback with an Object method function which requires input parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Let's say I have a class such as

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/bindNodeCallback';

export class MyClass {
    name: string;

    doSomethingWithName(cb: (err) => void) {
        const error = 'I have no name';
        const success = 'My name is: ' + this.name;
        if (!this.name) {
            return cb(error)
        }
        return cb(success);
    }

    doSomethingWithNameAndParam(param: string, cb: (err) => void) {
        const error = 'I have no name and param value is: ' + param;
        const success = 'My name is: ' + this.name + ' and my param value is :' + param;
        if (!this.name) {
            return cb(error)
        }
        return cb(success);
    }

}
```

`MyClass` defines a couple of methods which expect a callback as their last parameter.

I would like to use the `bindNodeCallback` method of **rxjs.Observable** to create a function which returns an **Observable** that I can use instead of the callback.

Everything works fine for the first method, i.e. the method which is not expecting other parameters than the callback. Here is the code that returns the the Observable

```
export function myClassObjFunctionObs(myObj: MyClass): Observable<MyClass> {
    return Observable.bindNodeCallback(myObj.doSomethingWithName).call(myObj);
}
```

and this is the code that uses that Observable

```
import {MyClass} from './my-class';
import {myClassObjFunctionObs} from './my-class';

const myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.name = 'I am your class';

myClassObjFunctionObs(myClass)
.subscribe(
    data => console.log('data', data),
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('DONE')
)
```

My problem is that I do not know how to do something similar with the method `doSomethingWithNameAndParam`, i.e. the method that expects a parameter before the callback.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to accomplish. Are you just trying to bind a parameter as you bind `this`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the most simple and obvious way to bind the param:

```
export function myClassObjFunctionObs(myObj: MyClass): Observable<MyClass> {
    return Observable.bindNodeCallback(myObj.doSomethingWithNameAndParam.bind(myObj, 'TEST PARAM')).call(myObj);
}
```

Also, you can consider changing your doSomethingWithNameAndParam function into a wrapper with a closure that curries the param and return a `doSomething` function:

```
doSomethingWithNameAndParam(param: string) {
    return (cb: (err) => void) => {
      const error = 'I have no name and param value is: ' + param;
      const success = 'My name is: ' + this.name + ' and my param value is :' + param;
      if (!this.name) {
          return cb(error)
      }
      return cb(success);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
export function myClassObjFunctionObs(myObj: MyClass): Observable<MyClass> {
    return Observable.bindNodeCallback(myObj.doSomethingWithNameAndParam('TEST PARAM')).call(myObj);
}
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-za2y2k